# Set data to programmatically opened View in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, e4

I am somehow stuck with my little project based on Eclipse e4.

There is some handler, reacting to a menu item, which should travel a list of data-objects and open a ViewPart for each entry in the list of data-objects. Each part should show detailed information of one of the data-objects.
The behaviour is similar to the eclipse IDE in the way, that clicking on a file in the package-explorer opens an editor-view showing the contents of the exact file. Though of course, I am not showing files in a code-editor but an overview representation of the selected data-object.

The list currently hast no UI representation as a List or a ListViewer, so I feel this may not be a situation where SelectionService would help, unless I got something wrong.

I found some older solutions here, where people suggeset extending the View with some setter methonds, then cast to that type and call these methods. But as far as I understand, with the new e4 framework, creating a part does only return a MPart, which then at a later point in time delegates to my custom code to populate the ui, so the is nothing to extend.

Basically I would like to do something similar to this code example, where the commented lines are the ones I am stuck with. Taken from the [example from Lars Vogel](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/12/07/eclipse-e4-create-a-new-part-dynamically/) :

```
MPart part = MBasicFactory.INSTANCE.createPart();
part.setLabel(crawl.getDomain());
part.setContributionURI("bundleclass://[...].parts.OverviewView");
part.setCloseable(true);
List<MPartStack> stacks = modelService.findElements(application, "[..].partstack.overview", MPartStack.class, null);
stacks.get(0).getChildren().add(part);
partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);

// missing call here!
// do some call to tell part, which details to show.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your class (`OverviewView` in this case) using:

```
OverviewView myView = (OverviewView)part.getObject();
```

you can then call a method you define in `OverviewView`.